# Spring MVC project without a model

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to create an application that show me the result of a division of two numbers by clicking a submit button !! My question is can I do that without using a model and in the jsp file without using the `<form action="resultat">` (in my case) .
The reason why i ask this because in class when I tried to use the `<form></form>` my teacher told me to try an other solution and he refused to give me the answer ! please help me I'm confused !! after all this i tried to make it work with a model but i couldn't

**My model**

```
public class Division {

private BigDecimal diviseur;
private BigDecimal dividende;
private BigDecimal resultat;

public BigDecimal getDiviseur() {
    return diviseur;
}
public void setDiviseur(BigDecimal diviseur) {
    this.diviseur = diviseur;
}
public BigDecimal getDividende() {
    return dividende;
}
public void setDividende(BigDecimal dividende) {
    this.dividende = dividende;
}
public BigDecimal getResultat() {
    return resultat;
}
public void setResultat(BigDecimal resultat) {
    this.resultat = resultat;
}

}
```

**My controller**

```
@Controller
public class DivisionController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/acceuil", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView acceuil() {
    return new ModelAndView("acceuil", "division", new Division());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/resultat", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String resultat(Model model,Division dvision,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,    BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "acceuil";
    }

    try {

        BigDecimal resultat = dvision.getDividende().divide(dvision.getDiviseur());
        dvision.setResultat(resultat);

    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        popup(redirectAttributes);
        return "acceuil";
    }
    return "show1";
}

public String popup(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("page_error","Division par 0 interdite");
    return "acceuil";
}
}
```

**this is my jsp file !!** 
the tomcat server tells me that i have an error in this line  how can i fix it !! also , is this the right way to display the result of the division ?? :

```
</head>
<body>

<form:form method="post" action="resultat" ModelAttribute="division">
    <label for="Dividende">Dividende :</label>
    <form:input id="Dividende" path="dividende" /> /
<label for="Diviseur">Diviseur :</label>
    <form:input id="Diviseur" path="diviseur" />
    <br>

    <button type="submit">Calculer</button>

    <br>
    <label for="resultat">Resultat de la division :</label>
    <output id="resultat" for="resultat" />
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your teacher don't want to give you the answer there is no reason for us to give it to you, isn't it ?

Comment: Just a clue : did you have recent lessons on JavaScript ?

Comment: @superbob : it's true ! but i'm in this now over a week and i'm realy fed up !! i've tried to look for a solution but i couldn't i'm still a beginner !!

Comment: @SergeBallesta : no i didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better if you create a model that can handle nulls, that's why you should prefer `Wrappers` instead of `primitives`. Also this model should contain the result of the operation so it can be used as object for the input and the object to show the result as well.

```
public class Division {

    private BigDecimal dividend;
    private BigDecimal divisor;
    private BigDecimal result;

    @NotNull
    public BigDecimal getDividend() {
        return dividend;
    }

    public void setDividend(BigDecimal dividend) {
        this.dividend = dividend;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDivisor() {
        return divisor;
    }

    @NotZero
    @NotNull
    public void setDivisor(BigDecimal divisor) {
        this.divisor = divisor;
    }

    public BigDecimal getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(BigDecimal result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

[Create your own constrain](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html)t @NotZero. In your controller you should have something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/arithmetic-operations")
public class ArithemticOperationsController {
    @RequestMapping("/divide")
    public String divide(@Valid Divison division, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "DivisionInput";
        }
        BigDecimal result = division.getDividend().divide(division.getDivisor());
        division.setResult(result);
        return "DivisionInput";
    }
}
```

You should have a JSP like this that you can reuse for both success and error cases, that why I returned the same result.

**division.jsp**

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="division" action="/arithmetic-operations/divide">
....
</form:form>
```

You can get more information about using Bean Validation and setting up your Spring MVC environment [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/).

Comment: **i've made some changes in the topic ! please look up !! i made a model ! and i changed my controller !! i need some help i'm still beginner in this field !!! your help is appreciated **

Comment: @user3816569 use commandName in <form:form> as in my answer and remove ModelAttribute

Comment: ! thank you very much it did work !  but can you explain me why i didn't work with ModelAttribute ? because my teacher did i an exemple of a sign up form ! and in the jsp file he puted ModelAttribute !! last thing !! how can i display the result in the same page ? i succeded to display it in an other jsp file but i want it in the same one ! thank you again and may god bless you

Comment: @user3816569 To show the results in the same page you return the same string from your controller, check my answer it always returns "DivisionInput" that's the page it will show. Please accept the answer, click on the checkmark on the left side of my answer to show your gratitude :)

Comment: i know that in my controller i should return the same jsp file !! i did that ! but when i click the submit button on my server nothing happens !! i think i have a problem in my jsp file ! can you help with it ?? also is there any possiblity to do this exercices without the tag <form></form> ???

Comment: @user3816569 it should work by returning the same string, try debugging and check the log to see what is happening. The standard way to do this is by using form, Spring MVC expects model to bind that data from and to that object, that object in this case is "division". That's why you specify in <form:form commandName="divison"> . You should do it this way unless you have an special requirement for not doing so. If you have further questions please create another question to answer it.

Comment: yes it worked ! i've changed this : `<output id="resultat" for="resultat" />` to this  : `<output>${division.resultat}</output>`
Thank you again